# Why can't this method in a server be found?

Tags: django

I am working on a new Django project that we uploaded to a server. The problem is that there is a method that is supposed to be called by an API we made. That API is used in another project, and that project works fine.

I think it's a matter of my urls or some configuration that I can't think of, since it doesn't say there's an error, it just gives a "Not Found" page when the method url is typed, and the logs on the server say `2020-06-08 17:43:43.337 WARNING log - log_response: Not Found: /whatsapp/get_response/`

The project's urls are:

```
from reportes.views import Home
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('orders/',include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('whatsapp/',include('whatsapp.urls', namespace='whatsapp')),
    path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And the app which has the method (whatsapp) has these urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from whatsapp.conversation import get_response_dialog
from .views import webhook_pedidos

app_name = 'whatsapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('get_response/', get_response_dialog, name='get_response'),
    path('webhook_pedidos/', webhook_pedidos, name='webhook_pedidos'),
]
```

The method exists and is there, ctrl+click takes me there on Pycharm.

The app is registered like this in the settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "django_tables2",
    'crispy_forms',
    'bootstrap3',
    'django_filters',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # Apps
    'orders',
    'core',
    'whatsapp',
]
```

Comment: maybe your view raised a 404 error?

Comment: Well, I have logs (and a call to another method which sends me a whatsapp message as an alert) right at the beginning of the method, and neither the log nor the other method is called, so if it doesn't even do the first line, which is a log, I asume the problem is that it's not even reaching the method, or not?

Comment: assuming you are not trying to do a hot debugging in production server, you can try to set `debug=True` in your `settings.py` and you can see a list of tried URLs